# Legend colors do not always correspond to the values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bundle-layout

This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsq05oq9/6/).

For some reason, the colors of some groups do not match the value of `size`.

For instance, I checked `"name":"flare.analytics.cluster.AgglomerativeCluster","size"‌​:3938`. In the drawing it's marked in "pink-red" color which corresponds to the legend > 5000 (scroll right to see the legend). According to my understanding it should be marked in the color of the legend `2000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For some reason, the colors of some groups do not match the value of `size`.

Well, the explanation is simple: you're not using `size` as the variable to paint your links. Instead of that, you're using the length of the `imports` array inside each node:

```
.style("stroke", function(d){
    return colorScale(d.target.imports.length)
})
```

And this is your domain:

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

Besides that, you're colouring by the length of the `import`array of the *target*, not by the length of the import array of the node itself.